# Firebase data being fetched twice from one call

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have a collection view displaying images fetched from Firebase in one of my view controllers, `FeedViewController` - in that controllers `viewDidLoad` I fetch the images with a `fetchPosts` function (I also remove all posts before fetching otherwise they appear twice - let me know if this is not a good way of doing this):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    posts.removeAll()
    following.removeAll()
    fetchPosts()
}
```

And I have several "show" segues to `FeedViewController`, all of which work fine, the feed loads as it should - all the images appear once. However, I have one segue that is called after a user chooses an image to upload, that somehow causes the images to be fetched (and thus appear in the CV) twice. The segue is called in the upload function here:

```
func uploadToFirebase() {
    AppDelegate.instance().showActivityIndicator()

    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://cloudcamerattt.appspot.com")
    let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key
    let imageRef = storage.child("posts").child(uid).child("\(key).jpg")
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.previewImage.image!, 0.6)
    let uploadTask = imageRef.put(data!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            AppDelegate.instance().dismissActivityIndicator()
            return
        }
        imageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in

            if let url = url {
                let feed = ["userID" : uid,
                            "pathToImage" : url.absoluteString,
                            "likes" : 0,
                            "author" : FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.displayName!,
                            "postID" : key] as [String : Any]

                let postFeed = ["\(key)" : feed]
                ref.child("posts").updateChildValues(postFeed)
                AppDelegate.instance().dismissActivityIndicator()

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showFeed", sender: nil)
            }
        })
    }
    uploadTask.resume()
}
```

It seems like the segue is in the correct place within that function (again correct me if I'm wrong), but like I said, when the user chooses an image and taps the post button and the above function is called, they are taken back to the feed controller and the image they posted, along with all the other images currently in the feed, are displayed twice (sometimes three times). I'm not sure why this is happening. If I navigate off the feed and come back (via the other segues to the feed), the images are displayed properly again - i.e all images appear only once.

So since the other segues work fine, I feel like the problem isn't in the segues, or in the way `FeedViewController` handles fetching & populating the CV (although it might be inefficient). It has to be in the upload function. And like I said, I can't see any more logical place to call the segue within that function. Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

EDIT: My `fetchPosts()` function:

```
func fetchPosts() {

    var posts = [Post]()

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        let users = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]

        for (_, value) in users {
            // get uid as string
            if let uid = value["uid"] as? String {
                // check to make sure uids match
                if uid == FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
                    // check for followers
                    if let followingUsers = value["following"] as? [String : String] {
                        // loop through those and add them to "following" array
                        for (_, user) in followingUsers {
                            self.following.append(user)
                        }
                    }
                    // add current user to that array also so you can see your own posts
                    self.following.append(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)

                    ref.child("posts").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value, with: { (snap) in

                        let postsSnap = snap.value as! [String : AnyObject]

                        for (_, post) in postsSnap {
                            if let userID = post["userID"] as? String {
                                for each in self.following {
                                    if each == userID {
                                        // here are the posts that the user should see (his own and his following)
                                        let posst = Post()
                                        if let author = post["author"] as? String, let likes = post["likes"] as? Int, let pathToImage = post["pathToImage"] as? String, let postID = post["postID"] as? String {

                                            posst.author = author
                                            posst.likes = likes
                                            posst.pathToImage = pathToImage
                                            posst.postID = postID
                                            posst.userID = userID
                                            if let people = post["peopleWhoLike"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                                                for (_, person) in people {
                                                    posst.peopleWhoLike.append(person as! String)
                                                }
                                            }
                                            posts.append(posst)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    ref.removeAllObservers()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the fetchPosts() method? Put it in your question, please.

Comment: @PieterLaebens just added it - although like I said the problem only occurs when I segue from the upload controller, the images fetch and load perfectly when coming from other controllers, which is why I thought the issue must be within the upload function.

Comment: Try using an `.observeSingleEvent` on the posts reference instead of `observe`, see if that changes anything, you seem to be removing the listeners after anyway.

Comment: @PieterLaebens That actually fixed it - why did that work? `.observeSingleEvent` ensures that it only fetches the posts once? Sorry if this is basic, I was following a tutorial and it wasn't made crystal clear what as going on behind the scenes.

Comment: I'll explain in answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `.observe` it will keep monitoring for changes. You use `removeAllObservers` after so I assumed you only needed the data once. In that case it's better to use `.observeSingleEvent` because that will only fetch the data once.

Here's what I think was happening, it's hard to tell without seeing the code executing. Since Firebase is asynchronous the code keeps executing and doesn't wait for Firebase commands to complete. I think you were segueing to your Feed before the updateChildValues actually completed. After arriving in FeedViewController you emptied your collections and loaded the data. The data would start loading, and while it was loading, the post would be added. Which triggered the `.value` again, since something changed in the database, causing it to run multiple times. And since you only clear your collections in your viewDidLoad, the duplicate posts would get appended to your collection.

To avoid this, replace `.observe` with `observeSingleEvent` or instead of using the `removeAll()` in your `viewDidLoad`, use it inside of your `.observe` (though you'd have to do it on the main queue I think).

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer and explanation! That does sound like what was happening, because there would be a lag for a second after the segue back to the feed controller, after which the CV would load with all the duplicate photos.